# TokBox OpenTok SDK for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have made proof of concept app for a video chat application in Xamarin Native using the below nuget packages (it works like a charm the source code is done by provider available here https://github.com/DreamTeamMobile/Xamarin.Opentok.Samples/tree/code-improvements)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.OpenTok.Android/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.OpenTok.iOS/

These nuget packages are basically a port of the native iOS/Android SDK's by TokBox for Xamarin, Created by DreamTeamMobile. I want to make use of them to for creating a Xamarin Forms application, I need some guidance how I can make the same functionality available to a Forms Project, considering that the package provider doesn't provides Xamarin Forms implementation. Would custom renderers help here.

Comment: Please tell us what do you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

In my case using Xamarin Forms (Shared Project), I used native views [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/) to made Room page and I used the given services to streaming from the Sample code [ref](https://github.com/DreamTeamMobile/Xamarin.Opentok.Samples), basically was copy and paste the services. Each service and whatever I needed from Android or iOS was included with Conditional compiler [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation).

I hope it's useful.